# How can I put text in the left margin using enumerate

Tags: enumerate, text-manipulation, leftmargin

I'd like to use`\begin{enumerate}` to create a list of numbered problems, but I want to place text to left of the numeral, in the margin, like this:

[image: Example problem text]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: There are dedicated packages for that, but if you do not want to use those you could do `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item How long do marmots hibernate?\reversemarginpar\marginpar{30pt} 
 \item How many hours do koalas sleep per day?\reversemarginpar\marginpar{30pt} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

The `tabto` package is useful in this regard.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, tabto,lipsum}
\newcommand\points[1]{\tabto*{-\leftmargin}\llap{#1 pts~~}\tabto{\TabPrevPos}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}

\item First item

\item \points{30}Next item

\item \points{5}Final item

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]